# ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'metadata' in installing mysql-python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

When I try install mysql-python to CentOs6.5 it casts a error

```
python /sw/ple.bkp/workspace/tianfd/TEMP/MySQL-python-1.2.5/setup.py install
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/sw/ple.bkp/workspace/tianfd/TEMP/MySQL-python1.2.5/setup.py", line 17, in <module>metadata, options = get_config()
   File "/sw/ple.bkp/workspace/tianfd/TEMP/MySQL-python1.2.5/setup_posix.py", line 32, in get_config
metadata, options = get_metadata_and_options()
   File "/sw/ple.bkp/workspace/tianfd/TEMP/MySQL-python-1.2.5/setup_common.py", line 12, in get_metadata_and_options metadata = dict(config.items('metadata'))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 642, in items
raise NoSectionError(section)
   ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'metadata'
```

I have tried to install mysql-devel and recompile Python, But the error doesn't fix. So,Could you give me some hints about this error?

Thank for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the case of `ConfigParser` not being able to read the `metadata.cfg` file. Try setting the right permissions to this file as well as `site.cfg`.